# Child class accessing parents class attribute with super without repeating arguments

Tags: python, inheritance, simplify

I want to access parent attributes from child class without having to repeat `super().__init__` arguments all the time

I've tried without super, I've tried `super().attribute`, I've tried setting default in parent class, or child class

Lets say I have the following situation:

```
class GM2_setup_to_convert:

    #Class to define which file to convert
    def __init__(self, file_name, path_to_folder):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.path_to_folder = path_to_folder
        self.file_to_convert = self.path_to_folder + self.file_name
```

Then I have several child classes like:

```
class Hardware_sheet(GM2_setup_to_convert):

    #Class to define hardware_sheet of file to convert
    def __init__(self, file_name, path_to_folder):
        super().__init__(file_name, path_to_folder)

        self.spec_excl_file_hardware = pd.read_excel(self.file_to_convert, sheet_name=' Hardware ', header=None)

class Expressions_cal(GM2_setup_to_convert):

    def __init__(self,file_name, path_to_folder):
        super().__init__(file_name, path_to_folder)

        self.spec_excl_file_cal_expr = pd.read_excel(self.file_to_convert, sheet_name=' Expression Calculation ', header=None, skiprows=[0, 1])
```

and so on. Now, if I want to instantiate an instance of the child classes, is there a way to avoid having to write the super().**init**(file_name, path_to_folder) arguments (see below) with every instantiation?

```
expr = Expressions_cal(file_name, path_to_folder)
```

E.g. like:

```
class GM2_setup_to_convert:

    #Class to define which file to convert
    def __init__(self, file_name=default, path_to_folder=default):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.path_to_folder = path_to_folder
        self.file_to_convert = self.path_to_folder + self.file_name
```

or:

```
class Expressions_cal(GM2_setup_to_convert):

    def __init__(self,file_name=default, path_to_folder=default):
        super().__init__(file_name, path_to_folder)

        self.spec_excl_file_cal_expr = pd.read_excel(self.file_to_convert, sheet_name=' Expression Calculation ', header=None, skiprows=[0, 1])
```

Comment: No (how would the parent attributes be set if you don't pass them in at some point...?)

Comment: If you use: `super().__init__()` in your child class, then default parameters from parent class will be taken.

Comment: @thebjorn: No they are instantiated once in the beginning, but I don't want to rewrite the argument when instantiating a child class. E.g. x = GM2_setup_to_convert("file_name", "path_to_folder") but I don't want to write y = Excpressions_cal("file_name", "path_to_folder").

Comment: Take the lesson [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: @ Relandom: Really? because I think when I do that, it tells me: 2 positional arguments are missing.

Comment: You are creating an _instance_ of your parent class to hold the data. When you sub-class, there is no data connected to the parent _class_. It sounds like you should be using a sub-class level context object to hold the data common to all instances of the subclass...?

Comment: Hmm what do you mean exactly by " a sub-class level context object to hold the data common to all instances of the subclass"? Do you mean class variables as data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you use a full path as a parameter. Then if you want to split it, you can use for example `path, file_name = os.path.split()` or like below:

```
import os
class GM2_setup_to_convert:

    def __init__(self, path="default_path"):
        self.file_name = os.path.basename(path)
        self.path_to_folder = os.path.dirname(path)
        self.file_to_convert = path


class Expressions_cal(GM2_setup_to_convert):

    def __init__(self, path=None):
        if path:
            super().__init__(path)
        else:
            super().__init__()  # In this case defaul value from class above will be taken.

        self.spec_excl_file_cal_expr = pd.read_excel(self.file_to_convert, sheet_name=' Expression Calculation ', header=None, skiprows=[0, 1])
```

Now you have 2 ways to create `Expressions_cal` object.

```
obj1 = Expressions_cal('new_path_to_file')  # pass 'new_path_to_file' as parameter
obj2 = Expressions_cal()  # takes defaul parameter ('default_path') from parent class
```